# Access denied to access `location.hostname` on IE7

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, internet-explorer-7

In IE7 if `location.hostname` read before changing `document.domain`, after changing document.domain `location.hostname` can not be read anymore!!

```
alert(window.location.hostname);
document.domain = document.domain;
alert(window.location.hostname);  // Access denied on IE7!
```

here is jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/yQwam/1/

and direct link to the page: http://fiddle.jshell.net/yQwam/1/show/

Comment: `document.domain = document.domain;` ?

Comment: touching `document.domain` is used when a page wants to access iframes from subdomains.

Comment: No. You should set the value of `document.domain` of parent frame and child frame to same value.

Comment: Yeah, line 2 makes no sense. If you wish to control Iframes, set document.domain on all DOM's(domain/subdomains): 

document.domain = location.host.replace(/^.*?([^.]+\.[^.]+)$/g,'$1');

Comment: Ofcourse, This is the code of the parent page!!

Comment: On the parent page, I should set document.domain, but after changing document.domain, window.location.hostname cannot be read on IE7.